# Use underscore as variable in Parallel Assignment

Tags: ruby, irb

In the following, variable `_` (underscore) is an `Array`, `foo == "foo"`, and `bar == "bar"`.

```
_, foo, bar = ["", "foo", "bar"]
_ # => ["", "foo", "bar"]
```

Can someone explain what the underscore does and where it is useful to use?

Comment: in `IRB` this trick not work. In `IRB`  underscore it last evulatet variable, but in the script it's unused variable.this work different on `IRB` and script.

Comment: @simone please look full comment.

Comment: @Monk_Code oh okay, that makes sense. I didn't know that in irb the underscore has a special meaning!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In parallel assignment, we sometimes do two things :

- ignore one element ( taking care of `_`)

You can reuse an **underscore** to represent any element you don’t care about:

```
a, _, b, _, c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a # => 1
b # => 3
c # => 5
```

- ignore multiple elements ( taking care of `*` )

To ignore multiple elements, use a **single asterisk** — I’m going to call it a **‘naked splat’** for no better reason than that it sounds a bit amusing:

```
a, *, b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a # => 1
b # => 5
```

Read this blog post [*Destructuring assignment in Ruby*](http://po-ru.com/diary/destructuring-assignment-in-ruby/) to know more other related things.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore is simply a placeholder for the variable assignment you're doing there. In your case it basically means ignore the first value in the array. If we didn't have it, you'd do something like this:

```
ignored, foo, bar = ["", "foo", "bar"]
=> ["", "foo", "bar"]
```

then not use ignored for anything. It's nicer to use _

Comment: And the script won't give a warning when run with `ruby -w`.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a variable like any other. You could have used `quux` or whatever other name you like.

Except … you would get a warning about an unused local variable named `quux`, whereas variables whose names start with `_` don't get a warning. This is an encoding of a convention to use `_` as the name of a variable that you want to ignore.

Comment: Could you [look into this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973537/operator-precedence-of-unary-operators) ?